# How to find the blog feed URL from the blog site programmatically

Tags: java, rss, blogs, google-reader, rome

We use the following code to read a RSS | ATOM feed, is there a way to find the RSS | ATOM URL of a blog feed give the blog site (e.g. `for http://my.typepad.com or http://occupylosangeles.org/`). This should be similar to what google.com/reader does.

```
import com.sun.syndication.feed.atom.Feed;
import com.sun.syndication.feed.module.Module;
import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndCategory;
import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndContent;
import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndEntry;
import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed;
import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeedImpl;
import com.sun.syndication.fetcher.FeedFetcher;
import com.sun.syndication.fetcher.FetcherEvent;
import com.sun.syndication.fetcher.FetcherListener;
import com.sun.syndication.fetcher.impl.FeedFetcherCache;
import com.sun.syndication.fetcher.impl.HashMapFeedInfoCache;
import com.sun.syndication.fetcher.impl.HttpURLFeedFetcher;
import com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedInput;
import com.sun.syndication.io.XmlReader;
    FeedFetcher fetcher = new HttpURLFeedFetcher(feedInfoCache);
    // register listener to feed
    FetcherEventListenerImpl listener = new FetcherEventListenerImpl();
    fetcher.addFetcherEventListener(listener);

    // Mechanism to read feeds via Rome Fetcher
    SyndFeed feed = fetcher.retrieveFeed(new URL(feedURL));
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no such feature in ROME, but there's a way. Look for a specific element in HTML source:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://url-of-an-rss-feed">
```

`rel` and `type` values should be exactly like this, and `href` will contain the feed's URL.

There's also a way to employ [AJAX Feed API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/#DiscoverFeeds) by sending a request like this:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/lookup?v=1.0&q=YOUR-PAGE-URL
```

The [source](http://blog.abelsky.com/2012/10/discovering-rss-feed-from-sites-main.html).

Comment: Is using this service needed any registered application key to access or its completely free?
Also i cannot find any details about `number of requests`count. Is the API depricated?